# Delphi knows if there's a new row after query refresh

Tags: delphi

I'm running a MySQL table with orders table from E-commerce running on VPS(Centos6).

I'm doing querys on desktop application that notify when there's a new order.
I have a query (TFDQuery) running at FormCreate event. I'm refreshing this query with a TTimer.

Is there some NATIVE way to know if a new row exists after refresh?

What i'm doing for now?

I'm counting rows number with query.RecordCount; After query on FormCreate, setting it to a public var. At the Timer event I'm doing the same thing but with local var.

-

```
public   
  a : integer;
 ....
```

FormCreate event after query result:

```
 a := query.RecordCount;
```

Timer event:

```
var 
  b: Integer;
begin
  query.Refresh();
  b:=query.RecordCount;
  if (b>a) then
  begin
    //do what i want to do
    a := query.RecordCount; 
  end;
end;
```

Well, everything works fine. But is this the right way? I've been searching around for a case like mine, but i didn't find anything.

Is there some native way to do it ?

I do have DevExpress components.

Comment: Are you refreshing with the TTImer for another purpose anyway, or just for determining added records?

Comment: I assume you don't have the possibility for rows to be deleted, as otherwise deletion + addition = no change according to your logic. Not aware of a native method, but depending on the nature of the query then checking the max of an autoinc field may be better/safer?

Comment: Why do you want to know if rows are added? Is this a multiuser situation? Plaese [edit] and update your question.

Comment: It's a simple app that select order list from MySQL running on VPS. It notify the business owner that's there a new order.

Comment: @MattAllwood It's fine, I have only a radiogroup that change the ''situation'' column with boolean value... The primary query shows only FALSE value. After updating value to TRUE, I refresh the query and set arrowcount again to variable... anyway, it's working fine. I was just looking for a native way to do it... like TFDEventAlerter from MartynA answer, but i'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your reference to `FDQuery`, I assume you're using FireDAC, so in theory you should be able to do this using a `TFDEventAlerter`, which can receive events from various RDMSs and feed them to your app as Delphi-style events.

See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29

Unfortunately now that you've mentioned in a comment that your RDMS is MySQL, I don't think `TFDEventAlerter` will help, because I don't think its amongst the RDMSs that `TFDEventAlerter` supports.  I don't think MySQL can provide the types of notification that `TFDEventAlerter` needs.  But don't take my word for it, try it.

Btw, if your table rows have a row ID column, then a way to find out whether rows have been added by another user with less load on the server than doing a full refresh is to make a record of the highest ID your query returns and periodically do a

```
Select Count(*) from mytable where ID > :ID
```

and only refresh your query if that returns a value greater than zero.

Btw, in some Delphi versions prior to XE8, there is a `TFDEventAlerter` demo:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDEventAlerter.

but this demo seems to be missing from XE8 (in my set-up, at any rate) and the ones from earlier versions won't compile in XE8 because of changes made in the FireDAC.Stan.Intf unit.

Comment: I found out why I couldn't initially get OnAlert to fire and updated my answer.

Comment: I found something like this on internet, but this don't works on MySQL,  it does ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were using MySQL, but if you are, I don't think TFDEventAlerter will help - MySQL is not listed amongst the RDMSs in the DocWiki article in my answer and in any case I think I've read somewhere that MySQL has no native support for providing the kind of events TFDEventAlerter uses.  Btw, you should have mentioned the RDMS you are using in your q.

Comment: Btw, I've edited the reference to MS Sql Server out of my answer because it's not relevant since you now say you're using MySQL.

Comment: Well... u should let it, maybe somebody need it on future. :) thank you anyway.

Comment: Well, the question of db change notifications crops up quite often on SO, so next time someone asks about MS SQL, maybe I'll be able to help them.  Anyway, I believe I've answered your question correctly, even if it wasn't the answer you were hoping for, so it would be good if you could be so kind as to accept it.